# How can I get the RGBA colors used in this frame?

Tags: inkscape, color-reproduction

I am trying to replicate the iconic air-mail frame for a project I have. Below is the picture. How do I get the RGBA colors used? I am using Inkscape.

[image: Airmail colors]

Answer (score 1):

Well, after looking on different places, I’ve found the tool I was looking for. Just using dropper tool by hitting <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd> and this will pick whatever color is desired.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. If you are satisfied with the answer you found, you can and should accept it (by clicking the checkmark next to it).